# FFMPEG how to Add timecode Track after Concatenation

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.webm -i input3.mov \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0] \
[2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mkv
```

How to add the Timecode track after concatenation.

### timecode : 09:59:59:10

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:01:00.000 -i Input1.mp4 -ss 00:01:00.001 -t 00:01:00.000 -i Input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v] [a]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -aspect 4:3 -s 352:288 -coder 1 -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -video_track_timescale 25 -g 12 -r 25 -bf 2 -refs 1 -x264-params "keyint_min=12:nal-hrd=cbr:b-pyramid=0" -b:v 2000k -minrate 2000k -maxrate 2000k  -map "[a]" -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -vbr 4 -ac 2 -async 1 -timecode 09:59:59:10 -f mov 18785_V1.mov
```

---

**Media Info:**
Other
ID                                       : 3
Type                                     : Time code
Format                                   : QuickTime TC
Duration                                 : 2 min 0 s
Time code of first frame                 : 09:59:59:10
Time code, striped                       : Yes
Language                                 : English

### Default                                  : No   >> how do I make it as default?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtNaa.png)

Comment: i have tried like this and the Output showed in Media info but in the Quick time player it's not showing the Timecode track

Answer (score 0):

The timecode is written as a generic tag in Matroska, so

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4  ... -map "[outa]" -timecode 09:09:55:00 output.mkv
```

ffprobe and mediainfo will show this as part of global metadata.

Comment: ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:01:00.000 -i Input1.mp4 -ss 00:01:00.001 -t 00:01:00.000 -i Input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v] [a]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -aspect 4:3 -s 352:288 -coder 1 -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -video_track_timescale 25 -g 12 -r 25 -bf 2 -refs 1 -x264-params "keyint_min=12:nal-hrd=cbr:b-pyramid=0" -b:v 2000k -minrate 2000k -maxrate 2000k  -map "[a]" -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -vbr 4 -ac 2 -async 1 -timecode 09:59:59:10 -f mov 18785_V1.mov

Comment: i have tried like this and the Output showed in Media info but in the Quick time player it's not showing the Timecode track

Comment: I thought you wanted to convert to MKV. SHare a small MOV file that does show timecode in QT.

Comment: I want to convert the MP4 to MOV file and Add Timecode track & Hint Track